How we can convert a _VariadicView_UnaryViewRoot to _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot (to access the child views of containers)in SwiftUI?
I created a custom VStackLayout and a custom DividedLayout like in code below:
struct VStackLayout: _VariadicView_UnaryViewRoot {
    func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
        return children
    }
}


struct DividedLayout: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
     func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
         return  children
    }
}

And then I am using them for making CustomVStackV1 and CustomVStackV2 like in code below:
struct CustomVStackV1<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {

        _VariadicView.Tree(VStackLayout()) {
            content
        }
 
    }
}


The use case of them would be like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            VStack {
                Text("First")
                Text("Second")
                Text("Third")
            }
            .border(.yellow)
            
            
            CustomVStackV1 {
                Text("First")
                Text("Second")
                Text("Third")
            }
            .border(.blue)
            
            
            CustomVStackV2 {
                Text("First")
                Text("Second")
                Text("Third")
            }
            .border(.red)
            
            CustomVStackV2 {
                CustomVStackV1 {
                    Text("First")
                    Text("Second")
                    Text("Third")
                }
            }
            .border(.gray)
            
            
            CustomVStackV2 {
                VStack {
                    Text("First")
                    Text("Second")
                    Text("Third")
                }
            }
            .border(.green)

        }
    }
    
}


struct CustomVStackV2<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {

        _VariadicView.Tree(DividedLayout()) {
            content
        }
 
    }
}


As you can see, I have access to each child in the _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot setup, allowing me to apply modifiers to each of them separately, as demonstrated in the code and the photo with the red border. However, the issue arises when I try to do the same with a view of type _VariadicView_UnaryViewRoot, such as Apple’s VStack. I am looking for a way to break down the views into their child components to apply modifications to each child individually, similar to the example with the gray border in the code and photo. Currently, I am unable to break down the parent view to access its children, so the gray border gets applied to the entire stack as a single view. Because of this limitation, I’m looking for a way to convert a _VariadicView_UnaryViewRoot to a _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot, or, in other words, to access the child views of containers like VStack, HStack, ZStack, or Group.

In iOS 18 just use a ForEach

I am not using iOS 18, lower version.
